# Is automatic object deallocation a feature of ARC or a feature of the Objective-C language itself?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Picture yourself a program that doesn't use ARC so that we have to do manual reference counting. Is the act of automatically deallocating an object when it reaches a reference count of zero (0) done by ARC, or is it provided by the language (the compiler) itself regardless of the utilisation of ARC?

Answer (score 1):

Deallocating an object is part of the implementation of `-release`. From the [documentation for that method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571957-release?language=objc) (which is part of the `NSObject` *protocol*, not class):

> The receiver is sent a `dealloc` message when its reference count reaches 0.

This stuff completely predates ARC, so it obviously can't be dependent on ARC.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a feature of the Objective C runtime. ARC inserts `retain`/`release` calls for you (as well as some other magic).